# Delphi XE3 and higher not saving open IDE tabs on exit

Tags: delphi, ide, desktop

I'm running win 7(64Bit) Delphi XE3,

When I open a project in my old Delphi XE, it would open all the forms I had opened when I saved the project last.

How can I make XE3 have the same action ?

Obviously a simple question, but I can't find the setting to save the layout in XE3.

Answer (score 5):

You have to turn it on in `Tools->Options->Environment Options`. This is from XE3, but it's the same spot it's been in since Delphi 2 or 3:

[image: XE3 Autosave Options]

Just check the `Project desktop` item.

In Delphi 10 and 11, the option has been moved to Tools->Options->IDE->Saving and Desktop:

[image: Delphi 10 and 11 autosave option]

Comment: Delphi has changed too much for this information to be any value in Delphi 11.0 ... I can't seem to find that option in Delphi 11

Comment: @GregT: It's still there. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to set the "Project desktop" option in "Environment options" -> "Autosave options" (thats where the option is in D2010, but I think it hasn't changed for XE3).

*UPDATE*

OK, had a moment to check out the wiki - see the [Environment Options](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Environment_Options) topic.

Comment: Cant find that option anywhere in XE3, any chance it may have been removed ?

Comment: In D2010, when selecting from main menu "Tools" -> "Options" then the "Environment options" is the very first item in the "options list". Is it still there in XE3?

Comment: @Hendra Is the "Autosave options" and "Project desktop" checkbox too still there (when selecting the "Environment options")?