# Delphi 11.0 not saving open IDE tabs on exit (Pst. There is no Environment options in Delphi 11 vs XE3!!)

Tags: windows, delphi, tabs

I searched Stack Overflow and found my question... but it's over 10 years old and Delphi has changed so much since then.

This: [Delphi XE3 not saving open IDE tabs on exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701071/delphi-xe3-not-saving-open-ide-tabs-on-exit) Is not valid for Delphi 11.0.

I'm running Windows 10 and using Delphi 11.0

I want to be able to go back to any project with all the TABS I had left open when I closed the project, but Delphi always starts with the project TAB only and sometimes doesn't start with any TAB at all!

I searched and found my question on Stack Overflow, but the answer has changed, because Delphi 11 no longer has Environment options or the methods described in the answer.  All things have must have moved or no longer exist??

Your help is very welcomed!

Comment: I updated the linked question this morning to include recent Delphi versions, including an updated screen capture of the new location and dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after digging this is what I found: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Saving_and_Recovering

**For Delphi 11.0 make sure this is checked:**

**Tools > Options > IDE > Saving and Desktop > Save project desktop when closing**

What bothers me most is that the documentation on Embarcadero just seems to be copied over to the next version without much thought.

I found this: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Environment_Options and if you try to do Tools > Options > Environment Options ... YOU WON'T FIND IT!!! ... it's in the documentation, but it doesn't exist!

I hope this saves someone time and money!

Comment: Unfortunately Embarcadero isn't best at keeping Documentation updated which is a shame.

Comment: I [answered your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15705780/62576) this morning with updated information that says this already, and even included an image of the updated dialog.